# Apple Metal Element-wise Matrix Multiplication (Hadamard Product)

Tags: objective-c, swift, metal, metal-performance-shaders

Is it possible to perform a Hadamard Product using Apple's Metal Performance Shaders?  I see that a normal matrix multiplication can be performed using [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metalperformanceshaders/mpsmatrixmultiplication), but I am specifically looking for an element-wise multiplication, or a clever way to construct one.  (For instance, is it possible to convert a MPSMatrix into a MPSVector and then perform the product using vectors?)

UPDATE:
I appreciate the recommendation to use shaders!  I'm working on an implementation and this looks promising!  I will post the solution once I have something working.

Comment: Why don't write your own shader?

Comment: An `MPSMatrix` is backed by a `MTLBuffer`, so you could write a trivial kernel to do the multiplication. The kernel function would take three buffer parameters (two in, one out). You might need to take some care in indexing if your stride doesn't match your column count, but this is otherwise trivial (and [embarrassingly parallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel)).

Comment: There is also `MPSImageMultiply`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, answering my own question here based on recommendations from commenters- try writing my own shader!

Here's the shader code:

```
#include <metal_stdlib>
using namespace metal;

/*
 hadamardProduct:
 Perform an element-wise multiplication (hadamard product) of the two input matrices A and B, store the result in C
 */
kernel void hadamardProductKernel(
texture_buffer<float, access::read> A [[texture(0)]],
texture_buffer<float, access::read> B [[texture(1)]],
texture_buffer<float, access::write> C [[texture(2)]],
uint gid [[thread_position_in_grid]]) {
    // C[i,j] = A[i,j] * B[i,j]
    C.write(A.read(gid) * B.read(gid), gid);
}
```

And the swift that executes the shader on two 4x4 matrices:

```
import Foundation
import Metal
import MetalKit

guard
    let gpu = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice(),
    let commandQueue = gpu.makeCommandQueue(),
    let commandBuffer = commandQueue.makeCommandBuffer(),
    let defaultLibrary = gpu.makeDefaultLibrary(),
    let kernelFunction = defaultLibrary.makeFunction(name: "hadamardProductKernel")
else {exit(1)}

// Create the matrices to multiply (as row-major matrices)
var A:[Float] = [2,0,0,0,
                 0,2,0,0,
                 0,0,2,0,
                 0,0,0,2]

var B:[Float] = [1,0,0,0,
                 0,2,0,0,
                 0,0,3,0,
                 0,0,0,4]

let A_buffer = gpu.makeTexture(descriptor: MTLTextureDescriptor.textureBufferDescriptor(with: .r32Float,
                                                                                                                                                                                width: 16,
                                                                                                                                                                                resourceOptions: .storageModeManaged,
                                                                                                                                                                                usage: .shaderRead))
let B_buffer = gpu.makeTexture(descriptor: MTLTextureDescriptor.textureBufferDescriptor(with: .r32Float,
                                                                                                                                                                                width: 16,
                                                                                                                                                                                resourceOptions: .storageModeManaged,
                                                                                                                                                                                usage: .shaderRead))
let C_buffer = gpu.makeTexture(descriptor: MTLTextureDescriptor.textureBufferDescriptor(with: .r32Float,
                                                                                                                                                                                width: 16,
                                                                                                                                                                                resourceOptions: .storageModeManaged,
                                                                                                                                                                                usage: .shaderWrite))
A_buffer?.replace(region: MTLRegionMake1D(0, 16),
                  mipmapLevel: 0,
                  withBytes: UnsafeRawPointer(A),
                  bytesPerRow: 64)
B_buffer?.replace(region: MTLRegionMake1D(0, 16),
                  mipmapLevel: 0,
                  withBytes: UnsafeRawPointer(B),
                  bytesPerRow: 64)

let computePipelineState = try gpu.makeComputePipelineState(function: kernelFunction)
let computeEncoder = commandBuffer.makeComputeCommandEncoder()
computeEncoder?.setComputePipelineState(computePipelineState)
computeEncoder?.setTexture(A_buffer, index: 0)
computeEncoder?.setTexture(B_buffer, index: 1)
computeEncoder?.setTexture(C_buffer, index: 2)
let threadGroupSize = MTLSize(width: 16, height: 1, depth: 1)
let threadGroupCount = MTLSize(width: 1, height: 1, depth: 1)
computeEncoder?.dispatchThreadgroups(threadGroupCount, threadsPerThreadgroup: threadGroupSize)
computeEncoder?.endEncoding()
commandBuffer.commit()
commandBuffer.waitUntilCompleted()

print("done")
```

Appreciate any comments linking to resources for further learning about this kind of thing.

Answer (score 2):

Other option is to use MTLBuffers (in my example I store result in first input buffer):

```
#include <metal_stdlib>
using namespace metal;

kernel void hadamardProductKernel(
    device float *a [[ buffer(0) ]],
    const device float *b [[ buffer(1) ]],
    uint id [[ thread_position_in_grid ]]
)
{
    a[id] = a[id] * b[id];
}
```

Here the Objective C code which executes Hadamard product on two float32 arrays (`a->data` and `b->data`):

```
id<MTLLibrary> library = [device newDefaultLibrary];
id<MTLFunction> function = [library newFunctionWithName:@"hadamardProductKernel"];
id<MTLCommandBuffer> commandBuffer = [commandQueue commandBuffer];
id<MTLComputePipelineState> computePipelineState = [device newComputePipelineStateWithFunction:function error:NULL];
id<MTLComputeCommandEncoder> computeCommandEncoder = [commandBuffer computeCommandEncoder];
[computeCommandEncoder setComputePipelineState:computePipelineState];
id<MTLBuffer> buffer_a = (__bridge id<MTLBuffer>)(a->data);
[computeCommandEncoder setBuffer:buffer_a offset:0 atIndex:0];
id<MTLBuffer> buffer_b = (__bridge id<MTLBuffer>)(b->data);
[computeCommandEncoder setBuffer:buffer_b offset:0 atIndex:1];
MTLSize threadGroupSize = MTLSizeMake(<<ELEMENTS COUNT HERE>>, 1, 1);
MTLSize threadGroupCount = MTLSizeMake(1, 1, 1);
[computeCommandEncoder dispatchThreadgroups:threadGroupSize threadsPerThreadgroup:threadGroupCount];
[computeCommandEncoder endEncoding];
[commandBuffer commit];
[commandBuffer waitUntilCompleted];
```